# i want to test a method in a repository with events phpunit laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, repository

Hello everyone I am new to Unit testing and I am stuck on this

Here is the repository method I am testing =>

```
public function store(array $input){

        $input['billing_contact'] = (isset($input['billing_contact'])) ? 1 : 0;  
        \DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $new_contact = $this->model->create($input);

            //EVENT CREATE ACCOUNT (USER)
            event(new EventCreateUserWithContact($new_contact));
            \DB::commit();
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            \DB::rollback();
            return false;
        }


        return $new_contact;

    }
```

Here is the test that I am trying to make =>

```
class ContactTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithFaker;
    protected $contact;/**/
    protected $container;/**/

    public function setup()
    {
        parent::setup();
        $this->container = new \Illuminate\Container\Container();
        $this->contact = new Contact();
        DB::beginTransaction();
    }
    public function tearDown()
    {
        DB::rollback();
        parent::tearDown();
    }
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testContactRepo()
    {
//        Event::();
        $publisher = factory(\App\Models\Publisher::class)->create();
        $contact =  factory(\App\Models\Contact::class)->create();


//
        $data =  [

            'first_name' => $this->faker->word,
            'last_name'=>  $this->faker->word,
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'phone'=> 112321321,
            'job'=> $this->faker->word,
            'billing_contact'=> $this->faker->word,
            'approve_delete_at'=> $this->faker->date('Y-m-d',  '1461067200'),
            'publisher_id'=> $publisher->id,

        ];

        $rep = new ContactRepositoryEloquent($this->container);

        $contact = $rep->store($data);
    dd($contact);


    }
}
```

I do not understand how to get the new contact object because I got an exception error when I run the test (I get false)
Do I need to create a fake event to make it worked?

Comment: Hi. You should add your code to your question rather than link to images of it.

Comment: Copy your code here

Comment: Done guys ;) @Jonathon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution using =>

\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::fake();

It helps passing the events and continue with the testing!